# Save city of visitor into text file

Tags: javascript, php

Ive used this service in the past: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/ but dont know how to transfer the variable to my php text file.

I have a form on my page, instead of asking the visitor I want it to automatically get the city closest to the visitor. 100 percent accuracy is not important, thats why im not asking them.

It is generated by javascript:

Header:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>
```

Body where you want the location to appear:

```
<script language="JavaScript">document.write(geoip_city());</script>
```

I want the location to be attached to a hidden form field in the hidden input field id="city".

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" action="script.php">Email: <input    size="35" type="text" name="email"> 
<input type="hidden" id="city" name="city" value="">

<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit(); return false;" class="submit">Submit</a>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you Google'd "php write to file"?

Comment: if you want requests from server, you can create your xmlhttprequest, then do what you have to do. or just straight up submit the form, then just process it.

Comment: i think he wants the js to write to the form which is then submitted and processed by script.php

Comment: I can write  to fall. My problem is I do not know how to add the city value to the hidden form field.

The field reads: <input type="hidden" id="city" name="city" value="">

I want it to show the city in the "value" field: <input type="hidden" id="city" name="city" value="Detroit">